# how to implement a function like sum(2)(3)(4)......(n) in python?

Tags: python, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

how to implement a function that will be invoked in the following way `sum_numbers(2)(3)(4)......(n)`  in python?

the result should be `2+3+4+.....+n`

The hint that I have is since functions are object in pythons there is way to do those using a nested function but I am not sure.

```
def sum_number(x):
    def sum_number_2(y):
        def sum_number_3(z):
        ....................
            def sum_number_n(n)
                return n
            return sum_number_n
        return sum_number_3
    return sum_number_2
  return sum_number
```

But instead of writing so many nested functions we should be able to do it in couple nested functions to compute sum of n values when invoked in the following way `sum_numbers(2)(3)(4)......(n)`

Comment: `sum([2,3,4,...,n])` works fine...

Comment: `sum(i for i in range(2,n+1))` should work

Comment: nope thats not what I am looking for. The function will be invoked in the following way sum(1)(2)(3)....(n). And assume sum is not an inbuilt function

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing with the parentheses after each other... It's like you expect to return a function while also returning a value that can be summed...

Comment: @user1870400 The problem with your request is that if `sum(x)` returns a function, how do you go about getting the final sum?

Comment: There is way! I just learnt that today but I dont completely understand 100%. please read the hint

Comment: Maybe if you show what you learned in your question, we can help you understand better. As is, what you wrote can't return both a function and a value

Comment: cricket_007 I am not sure why you are stuck with returning a function and value. yes sum(x) does return function until n-1 calls but at the nth call it can return a value. Let me edit my post a bit

Comment: Because your function does not know when the nth call is in order to return a final value

Comment: cricket_007 There is a way in python. I made an edit and I cant explain any better but stay tuned you will see a solution

Comment: @user1870400: what makes you think there is a solution? How do you plan to detect the nth call?

Comment: @vaultah I guess no one is using the fact that functions are also objects.

Comment: Yes, they are. How is that supposed to help?

Comment: @vaultah Like I said stay tuned for the solution. Never say never

Comment: @vaultah wait and see

Comment: @user1870400 I just posted a solution using classes. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Python's data model features to convert the result into the desired type.

```
class sum_number(object):
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val

  def __call__(self, val):
    self.val += val
    return self

  def __float__(self):
    return float(self.val)

  def __int__(self):
    return int(self.val)

print '{}'.format(int(sum_number(2)(3)(8)))
print '{}'.format(float(sum_number(2)(3)(8)))
```

Answer (score 5):

You could create a subclass of `int` that is callable:

```
class sum_numbers (int):
    def __new__ (cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __call__ (self, val):
        return sum_numbers(self + val)
```

That way, you have full compatibility with a normal integer (since objects of that type *are* normal integers), so the following examples work:

```
>>> sum_numbers(2)(3)(4)(5)
14
>>> isinstance(sum_numbers(2)(3), int)
True
>>> sum_numbers(2)(3) + 4
9
```

Of course, you may want to override additional methods, e.g. `__add__` so that adding a normal integer will still return an object of your type. Otherwise, you would have to call the type with the result, e.g.:

```
>>> sum_numbers(sum_numbers(2)(3) + 5)(6)
16
```

Answer (score 3):

If your function is returning another function, you can't just chain calls together and expect a human readable result. If you want a function that does what you want without the final result, this works:

```
def sum(x):
    def f(y):
        return sum(x+y)
    return f
```

If you're fine with printing out the operations you can try this:

```
def sum(x):
    print(x)
    def f(y):
        return sum(x+y)
    return f
```

If you absolutely, absolutely need a return value then this is a dirty, horrible hack you could try:

```
def sum(x, v):
    v[0] = x
    def f(y, v):
        return sum(x+y, v)
    return f

v = [0]
sum(1,v)(2,v)(3,v)
print(v[0]) # Should return 6
```

Here's another solution that uses classes:

```
class sum(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0):
        self.x=x
    def __call__(self, *y):
        if len(y) > 0:
            self.x += y[0]
            return self
        return self.x

print(sum(1)(2)(3)()) # Prints 6
```

Comment: Could you not just `return x+y`?

Comment: @cricket_007 They expect a function in return.

Comment: Ah. Recursion. Gotcha.

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking for is not possible in Python since you aren't providing a way to determine the end of the call chain, as cricket_007 mentions in the comments. However, if you *do* provide a way to indicate that there are no more calls then the function is easy to code. One way to indicate the end of the chain is to make the last call with no arguments.

I'm using `rsum` (recursive sum) as the name of the function in my code because `sum` is a built-in function and unnecessarily shadowing the Python built-ins is *not* a good coding practice: it makes the code potentially confusing, or at least harder to read because you have to keep remembering that the name isn't referring to what you normally expect it to refer to, and can lead to subtle bugs.

```
def rsum(val=None, tot=0):
    if val is None:
        return tot
    tot += val
    return lambda val=None, tot=tot: rsum(val, tot)

print rsum(42)()
print rsum(1)(2)()
print rsum(4)(3)(2)(1)()
print rsum(4100)(310000)(9)(50)()
```

**output**

```
42
3
10
314159
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class MetaSum(type):

    def __repr__(cls):

            sum_str = str(cls.sum)

            cls.sum = 0

            return sum_str

    def __call__(cls, *args):

            for arg in args:

                    cls.sum += arg

            return cls



class sum_numbers(object, metaclass = MetaSum):
    sum = 0

print (sum_numbers(2)(3)(4)) # this only works in python 3
```

Comment: “this only works in python 3” – Yet, you’re using the Python 2 print statement there?

Comment: Also note that this may make it look like a number, but it isn’t one: For example `sum_numbers(2) + 4` will fail because you cannot add the type to an int.

Comment: What Poke said. FWIW, to make this code run in Python 2, replace `class sum_numbers(object, metaclass = MetaSum)` with `class sum_numbers(object):` followed by `__metaclass__ = MetaSum`