# How to construct `g` such that `g(x0)(x1)(x2) == f(f(x0, x1), x2)`

Tags: functional-programming

Given arbitrary function `f`, how to construct function `g` such that for every `x0, x1, ..., xn`, `g(x0)(x1)...(xn)` equals `f(...f(f(x0, x1), x2), ...), xn)`?

EDIT

This is very similar to the question [how to implement a function like sum(2)(3)(4)...(n) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236616/how-to-implement-a-function-like-sum234-n-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At every point g<sub>n</sub> has to return both a function that can accept x<sub>n+1</sub> and the value given by applying f to g<sub>n-1</sub> and x<sub>n</sub>. Unless you are using a language that allows the return value to be or act as both types, this is impossible.